# Chrome Extensions: Pass data from popup to another script file before the script is injected

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**Problem**
Let's assume I go to a website called RENT.com. Let's also assume for this chrome extension there is a script A (JS) that is injected to RENT.com. Script A is a large script file that does a lot of interacting with RENT.com's HTML elements such as form fields. **Before the script runs** however, it needs some DOM ID's of a couple elements such as the email field because it modifies them.

**Objective**

I'd like to create a couple input fields (let's call them InputEmail and InputName) in popup.html to enter in the ID's of the elements on RENT.com. Obviously I'd be looking up the ID's manually by viewing the source, this is intentional.

A button in popup.html let's call it "GO BUTTON" will then read the value of InputEmail and InputName and send it to Script A. Script A now has everything it needs to function properly and is now injected into the page.

The appropriate interactions from Script A and RENT.com are now completed.

I've tried a few things, read a ton of information from Docs and Stack but I don't understand I think fundamentally how this can work. I want to pass data to Script A via popup.js before I execute content_script which ultimately is just injecting Script A. Seems like a chicken/egg problem and I'm not hungry for breakfast or lunch ;).

Thanks guys!

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>

  </head>
  <body>
      <ul>
          <li><label>Email ID</label><input type="text" id="emailID"></input></li>
          <li><label>Company ID</label><input type="text" id="nameID"></input></li>
      </ul>
      <input type="button" id="Modify" style="" value="GO BUTTON"></input>
     <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Popup.js**

```
function click(e) {         
    //Ideally pass these values to Script A somehow
    var email = document.getElementById("emailID").value;
    var company = document.getElementById("nameID").value; 

   //then execute this or pass the ID's to content_script, inject into Script A, then inject into page
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:"contentscript.js"});        
    window.close();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var d = document.getElementById("Modify");
  d.addEventListener('click',click);

});
```

**ContentScript to inject Script A**

```
var s2 = document.createElement('script');
s2.src =chrome.extension.getURL("ScriptA.js");
s2.async = false;

s2.onload = function() {
    s2.parentNode.removeChild(s2);

};
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s2);
```

Comment: Why are you injecting `ScriptA` in the webpage context? Can't it run as a content script directly? That is, why aren't you doing `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:"ScriptA.js"});`?

Comment: I guess I could, you're right. But is that the answer to my question? I still need to pass data to scriptA...

Comment: No, the answer is now below :) I needed to know that to not overcomplicate the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish this. One would be:

```
function click(e) {
  var elementIDs = {
    email: document.getElementById("emailID").value,
    company: document.getElementById("nameID").value
  };
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'window.elementIDs='+JSON.stringify(elementIDs)
  }, function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "ScriptA.js"});        
  });        
  window.close();
}
```

This way, `ScriptA` will be able to access the values in `window.elementIDs`. This will work because content scripts from the same extension on the same page will share the execution environment, and the chaining of the calls to `chrome.tabs.executeScript` ensures that the script defining the global variable has run before `ScriptA` is run.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think it makes perfect sense, however when I place scriptA in the execute script it doesn't execute. It does add an async script within itself, I wonder if that's causing the issue. For some reason it works if I call it from the contentscript. Essentially ScriptA creates another script element called ScriptB which is set to load async. Any ideas?

Comment: and to add to this, when I place the code as you have above it does nothing. I tried writing to the console and having an alert in but that does nothing either. I remember this happened before and that's why I changed it so that the contentscript actually creates a script element instead of executing a script. Script A is doing some loading and calling an external API so that may be a possible cause, not really sure though. Thanks for the help!